# Getting an empty result for newQuery

Tags: google-maps, laravel-5

I've a problem in getting the value of the query $scholars for $lt = $scholars->lat.The result is empty array for dd($lt);

.Any help would be helpful to my school project.

database of Scholar

```
id          lat                 lng                 scholar_birthday            scholar_GPA
1           10.275667       123.8569163                 1995-12-12                  89
2           10.2572114      123.839243                  2000-05-05                  88
3           9.9545909       124.1368558                 2002-05-05                  89
4           10.1208564      124.8495005                 2010-05-05                  85




        $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

            $scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to));     
            $scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('scholar_GPA'),array($ship_gpa_from,$ship_gpa_to)); 





                $lt = $scholars->lat;
                $lg = $scholars->lng;
                $str = $lt.','.$lg;

                $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lt).','.trim($lg).'&sensor=false';

                $json = @file_get_contents($url);
                $data=json_decode($json);   

                $status = $data->status;
                $data->results[0]->formatted_address;

                dd($lt);
        $scholars = $scholars->get();
```

dd Result

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$lat

Comment: What's the result for `$scholars` ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

when you use the newQuery() you will still need to get() the result like such

```
 $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*')->get();
```

This however will retrieve a collection and not a single result so you will need to loop over this.

```
foreach($scholars as $scholar){
 $lt = $scholars->lat;
 dd($lt);
}
```

Comment: i update my code sir, 

i know sir but if i implement that other criteria will be affected